# MySQL Docker Image is always restarting status

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I followed step by step this article ( https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-20-04 ).

I just changed php version (8.1) instead of (7.4) and mysql version (8.0) instead of (5.7.22)

When I run (docker ps) command, digitalocean.com/php and nginx:alpine are fine. But mysql:8.0 is always restarting status.

But I tested firstly it in local development.

When local development, everything is okay.

Buy I deployed it in the droplet, I faced the error that MySQL is always restarting status.

When I run (docker logs -f ) command, I faced the following error.

- 2022-08-13 06:35:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
- 2022-08-13 06:35:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user ‘mysql’
- 2022-08-13 06:35:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
- ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’ -> ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’

When I run (docker run --restart=always mysql:8.0) command, I faced the following error.

- 2022-08-13 06:57:37+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script - for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
- 2022-08-13 06:57:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user ‘mysql’ 2022-08-13 06:57:38+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.30-1.el8 started.
- 2022-08-13 06:57:38+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
  You need to specify one of the following:
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Add user for laravel application
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www

# Copy existing application directory contents
COPY . /var/www

# Copy existing application directory permissions
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www

# Change current user to www
USER www

# Expose port 9000 and start php-fpm server
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  
  #PHP Service
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
      - app-network

  #Nginx Service
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      - app-network

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123123
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql/
      - ./mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
    networks:
      - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your `docker-compose.yml` and any relevant `Dockerfile`

Comment: That's pretty strange. You've set `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` in the compose file, yet the entrypoint is still complaining about a missing password?

Comment: please suggest to me, how should I set MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD?

Comment: Are you running `docker compose up`? You only mention running `docker run` which won't have your env config

Comment: yes, I run (docker-compose up -d) and then run (docker ps) that time I faced above error.